# how to upgrqde this function in php8.2

Tags: php, php-8.2

What is the best approach to check php version 8.1 and to upgrade in 8.2 the function.

```
  var_dump(phpversion()); ==> 8.1.7-1ubuntu3.2
  var_dump((float)phpversion()); ==> 8.1
```

thank you

Comment: There are code sniffers that check your code base for deprecations. One example is: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

Comment: What doesn't satisfy you currently with your code ?

Comment: I try to update my code to the next php version8.2 and 'static::link' does not work in 8.2

Comment: It would be better to use version_compare() function to check your PHP version. As float can be tricky with some numbers. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

Comment: What is the error message ? forward_static_call_array should be supported on 8.2

Comment: ok, my error everything is correct, update the question. Thank you

Comment: If you edit the question you should also edit the title. There's no "this function" any more.

Comment: [Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) is excellent for helping to get your code to work properly with a new version.

Answer (score 2):

There are some builtin constants that may be easier to use as they are not messed about with by per OS compilations

```
echo 'PHP_MAJOR_VERSION = ' . PHP_MAJOR_VERSION . PHP_EOL;
echo 'PHP_MINOR_VERSION = ' . PHP_MINOR_VERSION . PHP_EOL;
echo 'PHP_RELEASE_VERSION = ' . PHP_RELEASE_VERSION . PHP_EOL;
```

RESULT

My current version of PHP 8.2.1

```
PHP_MAJOR_VERSION = 8
PHP_MINOR_VERSION = 2
PHP_RELEASE_VERSION = 1
```